# SQL table getting info from another table based on a IF statement with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select

I am having a problem figuring out how to get column info from a different table then the one I am accessing through a SELECT command and to select certain cells of that column based on a IF statement. Here is the SQL code:

```
    SELECT Name, Age, Grant
    FROM table
```

now with the grant selection I want to access another table (having an IF statement where grant is). There would be 2 different grant values, which are "a" and "b". When the grant is "a" you would select the first column, first row of the second table, while the "b" variable would select the the second row of the first column in table 2. IF this can not be in done just in SQL then I am also working with asp.net/C#, but I would rather prefer it to be done in SQL. Also I am using a asp:SqlDataSource to gather the data from the SQL server. I thank everyone in advance for their help!

tables:

```
    table 1: with name, age and grant 
    --------------------
    |name    |Age|Grant|
    --------------------
    |jeff    |16 | A   |
    --------------------
    |jake    |21 | B   |
    -------------------- 

    table 2: with grant and grantReturn 
    -------------------
    |grantReturn|Grant|
    -------------------
    |spring     |  A  |
    -------------------
    |wintwe     |  B  |
    -------------------
```

sorry if the tables are not done so well. There are more info for table 1, but figure I would keep it simple with two people with different grants. For table 2 that is all the info there is. again thank you!

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you posted the relevant table schemas (tables & their columns) with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: I added an example of what the tables would be in my SQL database.

Comment: You'll want to use a join for that:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like what you want is a JOIN.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.age, t2.grantReturn
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Grant = t2.Grant
```

A sql join (in this case, an inner join), will take the rows from the first table, and match them to rows on a second table on a given condition. In this case, it says, for every table in  table 1, find the row in table 2 with the same Grant. Then in the select statement you can return any additional data from that table that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So you need to learn about `JOINS`

```
SELECT Name, Age, table.Grant, table2.grantreturn
FROM table
     inner join table2 on table.grant = table2.grant
```

see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html